# "Expanding" rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet, a screenshot of which is given here:
[image: Excel sheet]

If you look at the left hand side, there is a column of `Applications` and a column of `Accounts` which are approved `applications`... and then some dummy financial information. In row 2, for `Zip` `8701`, there are `9490` `Applications` and `7610` `Accounts`. I would like to expand this single row into 9490 rows, all with the same Zip and miscellaneous financial/demographic information, but with a binary 1 or 0 under `Approved/Disapproved` (a new column).

I'm basically wanting to turn this counts data into a lot of binary counts for ease of modeling, since right now Zips that have a lot of Applications get weighted quite heavily in the model. How can I do this in Excel? I'm not too familiar with macros, but I think that's the answer.

Comment: Do you mean columns?

Comment: @durbnpoisn No I would like 9490 rows all with the same values as row 2, only with the "Applications" and "Accounts" column gone and in its place a binary 1/0 column...so in those 9490 rows there would be 7610 rows with a "1" and 1880 rows with a "0"

Answer (score 1):

Try use macros:
A simple code here:

```
Option Explicit 
Sub DuplicateRows() 
     'Code modified from Stanley D Grom Ozgrid.com'
    Dim r As Long, lr As Long 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 28).End(xlUp).Row 
    For r = lr To 2 Step -1 
        Rows(r + 1).Resize(Cells(r, 28) - 1).Insert 
        Rows(r).Copy Rows(r + 1).Resize(Cells(r, 28) - 1) 
    Next r 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

from [here.](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=162575)

Comment: Thanks for the response Nematollah...unfortunately it broke on the line `Rows(r + 1).Resize(Cells(r, 28) - 1).Insert`...and I don't know VB at all...any ideas? And what would the input be? The whole row?